# Trying to resolve PyLance error for "import spotipy"

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy, pylance

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
from cred import *

# authentication without user
client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id = CID, client_secret = SECRET)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager = client_credentials_manager)

playlist_link = "spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1DXa8NOEUWPn9W"
playlist_URI = playlist_link.split(":")[-1]

print(sp.playlist_tracks(playlist_URI))
```

PyLance keeps underlining first two imports with:
Import "spotipy" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)

I pip installed spotipy inside a venv, and the code does output the last print statement accurately, but PyLance is underlining the first two imports and won't color-code/show recommendations the spotipy method names and usage.

Tried pip uninstall'ing spotipy, re-installing it. Tried pip3 too. But nothing's working. I'm on VScode, and I added a ("python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/usr/local/bin/python3") line in the settings.json, but isn't doing anything.